# AWS API Gateway : Keys based authorisation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Currently we are using AWS API gateway and using Cognito Authoriser.

We are developing a CLI tool, which uses these APIs.

We have a Login API, which is called from the CLI client. The CLI client uses the ID token returned from the Login API, to make subsequent calls to other APIs.

Instead of this, we want to provide support keys based authentication.

When the user is created, keys should be generated. The user will store these keys into some config file.

The CLI should be able to make use of these keys to call the REST APIs.

Is this feasible with AWS API gateway and Cognito?

Comment: if your use IAM authorizer will it help to achieve what you need

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, we are following this IAM based approach now.